# Append styles to elements inside of an iframe using VueJS

Tags: vue.js, iframe, vuejs2

I have a modal screen which includes an iframe to send out agenda-items. Now I can't style the iframe itself since it's used somewhere else in this application too. I need to do some custom styling for this particular modal tho, because I gotta align some buttons on different places etc.

I found a piece of code to apply styling to the inner parts of the iframe but I couldn't get it to work. Mind you, I work in VueJS and converting regular JS to VueJS is not my forte. I really want to style some items tho...

```
  <div class="base-modal" style="min-width:1100px;">
    <div id="modal-tools">
      <button id="close-modal" type="button" class="mdi mdi-18px mdi-close" @click="$parent.close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="box-column">
      <iframe class="is-full-width" style="min-height:650px" id="the-iframe" :src="`crmtask/ical?crmtaskid=${crmtaskid}`" ref="iframe"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  mounted () {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('the-iframe')
    var css = document.createElement('style')
    css.type = 'text/css'
    var styles = 'body {' +
        '  background-color: lime;' +
        '  color: pink;' +
    '}'
    css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles))
    iframe.contentDocument.head.appendChild(css)
  },
  props: {
    crmtaskid: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I really want to be able to style some buttons e.d. inside of this iframe

Comment: Getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a third-party plugin, you can use [vue-friendly-iframe](https://officert.github.io/vue-friendly-iframe/#/home) or [vue-frame](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-frame).

[Vue-frame](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-frame) allows you to render the frame in a `div` and pass a class as well as style.

Comment: vue-friendly-iframe worked like a charm for me to change the inner elements of the iframe. Thank you!

Comment: update: thought it was what I was lookin for... unfortunately not ): Will try vue-frame tho